# How can I change the mouse pointer when mouse over text with QStyledItemDelegate?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I change the mouse icon when the mouse is over the text in item delegate?
I have this part, but I can't find any example to change the mouse pointer.

What am I missing?

```
   void ListItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                             const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
     if (index.isValid())
        {
      int j = index.column();
      if(j==4)
      {
       QString headerText_DisplayRole = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString() ;
       QApplication::style()->drawPrimitive( QStyle::PE_PanelItemViewItem, &option, painter );

       QFont font = QApplication::font();
       QRect headerRect = option.rect;
       font.setBold(true);
       font.setUnderline(true);
       painter->setFont(font);
       painter->setPen(QPen(option.palette.brush(QPalette::Text), 0));
       const bool isSelected = option.state & QStyle::State_Selected;    
       if (isSelected)
        painter->setPen(QPen(option.palette.brush(QPalette::HighlightedText), 0));
       else
        painter->setPen(QPen(option.palette.brush(QPalette::Text), 0));
       painter->save();    
       painter->drawText(headerRect,headerText_DisplayRole);
       painter->restore();
       bool hover = false;
       if ( option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver )
       {
           hover = true;
       }
       if(hover)
       {
        // THIS part i missing , how detect when mouse is over the text
        // and if its over how to change the icon of the mouse?
       }


      }
      else
      {
       QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you will need the mouse position. You can get it using the [`QCursor::pos`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcursor.html#pos) static function.

```
QPoint globalCursorPos = QCursor::pos();
```

Notice that the result is in global screen coordinates, so you will have to translate it in widget coordinates. Let's assume that the widget on which you are using the delegate is called `myWidget`. In order to do the translation you will need the [`mapFromGlobal`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapFromGlobal) function of `QWidget`

```
QPoint widgetPos = myWidget->mapFromGlobal(globalCursorPos);
```

Finally you are going to need the [`indexAt`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) from `QAbstractItemView` which returns the model index of the item at the viewport coordinates point.

If `myView` is the name of the view you are using then the index at the current position is:

```
QModelIndex currentIndex = myView->itemAt(widgetPos);
```

Notice that you may need the [`viewport()`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport) in order to be precise. In this case in order to map the global coordinates you will need:

```
QPoint viewportPos = myWidget->viewport()->mapFromGlobal(globalCursorPos);
```

Finally you have to check if the returned index from the `itemAt` is the same with the index in your `paint` function. If yes change the cursor to whta you want, else restore the default cursor

```
if(hover)
{
     QPoint globalCursorPos = QCursor::pos();
     QPoint viewportPos = myWidget->viewport()->mapFromGlobal(globalCursorPos);
     QModelIndex currentIndex = myView->itemAt(widgetPos);

     if (currentIndex == index)
         QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor)); 
     else
         QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor(); 
}
```

This is the basic idea. Another option would be to reimplement the `mouseMoveEvent` and implement the functionality there. Check [this blog post](http://daniel-albuschat.blogspot.com/2009/09/setting-mouse-cursor-for-qts-item-views.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you !!!! the blog post saved me after 2 days of searching