# Change cursor appearance in delegate

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm creating a delegate that displays clickable text. To indicate to the user that the text is clickable, I'd like to change the appearance of the cursor when it hovers over cells assigned to the delegate.

I see that there are [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131727/how-can-i-change-the-mouse-pointer-when-mouse-over-text-with-qstyleditemdelegate) to this type of problem out there, but these all seem to involve changes to the table model or view code, not the delegate code. (The linked solution will not work within a delegate because the delegate doesn't receive any events when the cursor is not hovering over a cell assigned to the delegate, so there would be no way to restore the standard cursor appearance once the cursor has left the cell.)

It would be nice to have a delegate that maintains this feature when used in different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker gave me a nice solution to this problem. When the delegate is initialized, the associated view should be supplied as its parent. Then, the delegate can install itself as the event filter for the view's viewport. Once this is done, you can define an `eventFilter()` method that can catch events even outside the bounds of cells that use the delegate, which will allow you to modify the appearance of the cursor as it leaves the cells.

```
class CursorDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        parent.setMouseTracking(True)
        parent.viewport.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, viewport, event):
        ...
```

It's probably bad form to reach into the view like this from the delegate, but it's the best solution I could find.